# ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator - Blazor validation - Package manager

Tags: blazor

which package manager must be installed to use **ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator** ?

one of the links said to use

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation

but there is no packager manager in the name

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct package. It is currently in pre-release (3.2.0-rc1.20223.4 at typing this)

If installing through Visual Studio NuGet screen check the "Include prerelease" option.

If using the Install-Package command from PowerShell specify the specific version using -Version

If using the dotnet CLI add --prerelease